# NGINX Reverse proxy based on presence of set of request headers?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

If a user request do not have a **set** of headers, then the reverse proxy response should be routed to a different back end server , else if the reqeust have those headers, than request must go to a different server.

Is it possible in NGINX and how do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you're using `x-backend-pool` for your request header,
you can use the following NGINX module to get what you want: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

The map directive allows you to set variables based on values in other variables, I've provided an example for you below:

```
upstream hostdefault {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

upstream hosta {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

upstream hostb {
    server 127.0.0.1:8082;
}

map $http_x_backend_pool $backend_pool {
    default   "hostdefault";
    a         "hosta";
    b         "hostb";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$backend_pool;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know valid characters to use in nginx variable names are only alphanumerical and underscore.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for that, looks like I overlooked that when writing the config.